# where i can learn about JVM debugger protocol?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

i want to do test and build simple debugger GUI in c++ that debugging Java 
as i read from view docs i will have to work with the JVM debugger protocol 
do any one here have experience with it? where can i learn about it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Virtual Machine Debug Interface (JVMDI) Reference](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html) at Sun would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The home of the official documentation is here: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/

There are links there to the APIs and the low-level wire protocols that Java debuggers can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the Eclipse Java IDE project source code... That is the best Java debugger I have used... if you can replicate that user experience, it would be phenomenal...

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto